# Close Tasks to Update in a SubProject

Tags: ms-project-server-2013

I am trying to lock tasks in a subproject using the PWA "Close Tasks to Update" view.  However, the subproject has linked tasks to other projects, and in the PWA view it is not registering the required task-level field (they are filled out in the project).

Does anyone know a workaround where I can lock tasks without it seeing the tasks from the subproject as missing required information?

I am using Project Server 2013.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I was able to work around the issue was the temporarily change the required task level field to not required.  While it was not required, I locked the tasks and published.  Once completed, I made the task level field required again.

We do not have my project managers and even few projects with tasks linked between sub-projects.  This may or may not be an option for your environment.  This was a low enough risk, that it was the only real option available to me.